# To edit an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to edit an array but i don't know how to start.

The array is

```
var products =
[
  "rose-S", 
  "rose-M", 
  "rose-L", 
  "rose-XL", 
  "rose-XL", 
  "blue-XS", 
  "blue-L", 
  "green-M"
]
```

And the structure needs to be

```
{ 
  "rose": { 
    "S": 1, 
    "M": 1, 
    "L": 1, 
    "XL": 2 
  }, 
  "blue": { 
    "XS": 1, 
    "L": 1 
  }, 
  "green": { 
    "M": 1 
  }, 
}
```

What I could to do?

Comment: [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) should be enough create this.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the array, and create an object. Split the item and take the `color` and the `size`. Create the `color` object if it doesn't exist. Create the sub-object of the `size` if it doesn't exist, and add 1 for the current color and size combination:

```js
const products = ["rose-S","rose-M","rose-L","rose-XL","rose-XL","blue-XS","blue-L","green-M"]

const result = products.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const [color, size] = item.split('-') // split and destructure to get the color & size
  
  if(!acc[color]) acc[color] = {} // init color if it doesn't exist
  
  if(!acc[color][size]) acc[color][size] = 0 // init the size if it doesn't exist
  
  acc[color][size] += 1 // add 1 to current color/size

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```